# Internet through a NAS and Time Capsule

Tags: network, time-capsule, nas

I have tried to use my Time Capsule as external storage and backup but finally realized it's not working very well. It is very slow.

So, I think I'm gonna buy a Synology NAS as most people recommended. Maybe a 215J.

Today, I have my modem connected to my TC acting as a fast router. That works well I think.

My question is, how do I connect my internet for best effect if I get a NAS? Modem > TC > NAS? Or how does it work?

Additional comments are welcomed!

Comment: What is your Time Capsule reference (ie. Year, version) ? What kind of modem do you have ? Does it only acts as a network bridge or does it comes with a router too ?

Comment: It was bought less than a year ago so I think it is the latest. I know it has a A/C network connection.

Answer (score 1):

The NAS won't have any routing ability so it's pretty sure that it won't be directly connected to the modem.
Your schema is what I recommend. I have exactly the same architecture with a modem, an Airport Express and a Synology DS215j.

```
Modem ---------------- TimeCapsule (as router) ------------------ NAS
       WAN Interface               |              LAN Interface
                                   | LAN / Wi-Fi
                             Other devices
```

You may need to configure your TimeCapsule to make some Port Forwarding if you want to access to your NAS from outside of your network (I highly discourage that because of network security issues).

That all for me.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any drawbacks or anything else I should think about with that configuration?

Comment: Also... Shouldn't I connect the NAS to the TC with a network cable?

Comment: No, I don't think you should have any drawbacks. That's a pretty classic network architecture for a NAS. And yes, you should connect your NAS to the TC with an Ethernet cable in order to stabilize the file transfers.